# Shared pointer inheritance without explicitly casting first

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

So, I am trying to do something like this

```
template <typename T>
void call(std::shared_ptr<Base<T>> b) {

} 


int main() {
   std::shared_ptr<Derived<int>> d = std::make_shared<Derived<int>>();
   call(d);
}
```

It cant resolve the inheritance because they are shared pointers. Ideally I don't want to use `static_pointer_cast` or something like that in main so I was looking for maybe a different way to cast it so that the user in main can still call the same function but not have to worry about casting.

My second approach was to use raw pointers so I tried something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void call(Base<T> * b) {
   std::shared_ptr<Base<T>> obj(b);
} 


int main() {
   std::shared_ptr<Derived<int>> d = std::make_shared<Derived<int>>();
   call(d.get());
}
```

Since Base is an abstract class I can't use make_shared so I have to do it this way to my knowledge but the problem then becomes that as soon as the `call` function's scope ends it deletes the pointer resulting in a double free error since the shared ptr in main also tries to delete this.

Are there any suggestions for something to try?

Comment: Why do you need a shared_ptr<Base> inside call()? Can you just use the `Base*` or for instance `const Base&` directly?

Comment: What compiler error do you get? [`shared_ptr` plays nicely with inheritance conversions.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/QccGjz)

Comment: @chris So i just updated the question. The derived and base classes are actually templated and the error I am getting is that there is no matching function.

Comment: The problem isn't with the conversion from `shared_ptr<Derived<T>>` to `shared_ptr<Base<T>>`. It's that the compiler can't automatically deduce `T`. `call<int>(d);` should work. There are probably other better solutions, depending on what `call` actually needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is a bad practice to use smart pointers wherever the ownership is not needed. In your case the `main` function owns the pointer, and there is no way the object is destroyed while the `call` function is being executed. So you may pass a raw pointer without problems (and that is even better because the interface doesn't require more than it needs). This however may not be true in case of multithreaded environment or if the `call` function has side effects storing the pointer (e.g. that is actually a `set` method if a class). In this case `shared_ptr` should be used indeed.

Next, you may create a `shared_ptr<Base>` initializing it with a pointer to `Derived`. You even don't need to have virtual destructor for deleting the object: shared_ptr knows the actual type:

```
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> d = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    // Ok to delete
}
```

Finally, there is no problem in casting `shared_ptr<Derived>` to `shared_ptr<Base>`. That is another instance of a shared pointer that points to the same counter.

Comment: I want to pass the shared ptr by value to extend the lifetime. Can you look at my new updated question. The derived and base classes are templated so i think that's what is causing the problem

Comment: Please provide the definition of both `Base<T>` and `Derived<T>`. I guess there is no inheritance.